# Extracting a constraint from a conjunction

Tags: scala, haskell, types, type-constraints

Here's a tree of Boolean predicates.

```
data Pred a = Leaf (a -> Bool)
            | And (Pred a) (Pred a)
            | Or (Pred a) (Pred a)
            | Not (Pred a)

eval :: Pred a -> a -> Bool
eval (Leaf f) = f
eval (l `And` r) = \x -> eval l x && eval r x
eval (l `Or` r) = \x -> eval l x || eval r x
eval (Not p) = not . eval p
```

This implementation is simple, but the problem is that predicates of different types don't compose. A toy example for a blogging system:

```
data User = U {
    isActive :: Bool
}
data Post = P {
    isPublic :: Bool
}

userIsActive :: Pred User
userIsActive = Leaf isActive

postIsPublic :: Pred Post
postIsPublic = Leaf isPublic

-- doesn't compile because And requires predicates on the same type
-- userCanComment = userIsActive `And` postIsPublic
```

You could get around this by defining something like `data World = W User Post`, and exclusively using `Pred World`. However, adding a new entity to your system then necessitates changing `World`; and smaller predicates generally don't require the whole thing (`postIsPublic` doesn't need to use the `User`); client code that's in a context without a `Post` lying around can't use a `Pred World`.

---

It works a charm in Scala, which will happily infer subtype constraints of composed traits by unification:

```
sealed trait Pred[-A]
case class Leaf[A](f : A => Boolean) extends Pred[A]
case class And[A](l : Pred[A], r : Pred[A]) extends Pred[A]
case class Or[A](l : Pred[A], r : Pred[A]) extends Pred[A]
case class Not[A](p : Pred[A]) extends Pred[A]

def eval[A](p : Pred[A], x : A) : Boolean = {
  p match {
    case Leaf(f) => f(x)
    case And(l, r) => eval(l, x) && eval(r, x)
    case Or(l, r) => eval(l, x) || eval(r, x)
    case Not(pred) => ! eval(pred, x)
  }
}

class User(val isActive : Boolean)
class Post(val isPublic : Boolean)

trait HasUser {
  val user : User
}
trait HasPost {
  val post : Post
}

val userIsActive = Leaf[HasUser](x => x.user.isActive)
val postIsPublic = Leaf[HasPost](x => x.post.isPublic)
val userCanCommentOnPost = And(userIsActive, postIsPublic)  // type is inferred as And[HasUser with HasPost]
```

(This works because `Pred` is declared as contravariant - which it is anyway.) When you need to `eval` a `Pred`, you can simply compose the required traits into an anonymous subclass - `new HasUser with HasPost { val user = new User(true); val post = new Post(false); }`

---

I figured I could translate this into Haskell by turning the traits into classes and parameterising `Pred` by the type classes it requires, rather than the concrete type it operates on.

```
-- conjunction of partially-applied constraints
-- (/\) :: (k -> Constraint) -> (k -> Constraint) -> (k -> Constraint)
type family (/\) c1 c2 a :: Constraint where
    (/\) c1 c2 a = (c1 a, c2 a)

data Pred c where
    Leaf :: (forall a. c a => a -> Bool) -> Pred c
    And :: Pred c1 -> Pred c2 -> Pred (c1 /\ c2)
    Or :: Pred c1 -> Pred c2 -> Pred (c1 /\ c2)
    Not :: Pred c -> Pred c

data User = U {
    isActive :: Bool
}
data Post = P {
    isPublic :: Bool
}

class HasUser a where
    user :: a -> User
class HasPost a where
    post :: a -> Post

userIsActive :: Pred HasUser
userIsActive = Leaf (isActive . user)

postIsPublic :: Pred HasPost
postIsPublic = Leaf (isPublic . post)

userCanComment = userIsActive `And` postIsPublic
-- ghci> :t userCanComment
-- userCanComment :: Pred (HasUser /\ HasPost)
```

The idea is that each time you use `Leaf` you define a requirement (such as `HasUser`) on the type of the whole without specifying that type directly. The other constructors of the tree bubble those requirements upwards (using constraint conjuction `/\`), so the root of the tree knows about all of the requirements of the leaves. Then, when you want to `eval` your predicate, you can make up a type containing all the data the predicate needs (or use tuples) and make it an instance of the required classes.

However, I can't figure out how to write `eval`:

```
eval :: c a => Pred c -> a -> Bool
eval (Leaf f) = f
eval (l `And` r) = \x -> eval l x && eval r x
eval (l `Or` r) = \x -> eval l x || eval r x
eval (Not p) = not . eval p
```

It's the `And` and `Or` cases that go wrong. GHC seems unwilling to expand `/\` in the recursive calls:

```
Could not deduce (c1 a) arising from a use of ‘eval’
from the context (c a)
  bound by the type signature for
             eval :: (c a) => Pred c -> a -> Bool
  at spec.hs:55:9-34
or from (c ~ (c1 /\ c2))
  bound by a pattern with constructor
             And :: forall (c1 :: * -> Constraint) (c2 :: * -> Constraint).
                    Pred c1 -> Pred c2 -> Pred (c1 /\ c2),
           in an equation for ‘eval’
  at spec.hs:57:7-15
Relevant bindings include
  x :: a (bound at spec.hs:57:21)
  l :: Pred c1 (bound at spec.hs:57:7)
  eval :: Pred c -> a -> Bool (bound at spec.hs:56:1)
In the first argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘eval l x’
In the expression: eval l x && eval r x
In the expression: \ x -> eval l x && eval r x
```

GHC knows `c a` and `c ~ (c1 /\ c2)` (and therefore `(c1 /\ c2) a`) but can't deduce `c1 a`, which would require expanding the definition of `/\`. I have a feeling it would work if `/\` were a type *synonym*, not a *family*, but Haskell doesn't permit partial application of type synonyms (which is required in the definition of `Pred`).

---

I attempted to patch it up using [`constraints`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.4.1.3/docs/Data-Constraint.html):

```
conjL :: (c1 /\ c2) a :- c1 a
conjL = Sub Dict
conjR :: (c1 /\ c2) a :- c1 a
conjR = Sub Dict

eval :: c a => Pred c -> a -> Bool
eval (Leaf f) = f
eval (l `And` r) = \x -> (eval l x \\ conjL) && (eval r x \\ conjR)
eval (l `Or` r) = \x -> (eval l x \\ conjL) || (eval r x \\ conjR)
eval (Not p) = not . eval p
```

Not only...

```
Could not deduce (c3 a) arising from a use of ‘eval’
from the context (c a)
  bound by the type signature for
             eval :: (c a) => Pred c -> a -> Bool
  at spec.hs:57:9-34
or from (c ~ (c3 /\ c4))
  bound by a pattern with constructor
             And :: forall (c1 :: * -> Constraint) (c2 :: * -> Constraint).
                    Pred c1 -> Pred c2 -> Pred (c1 /\ c2),
           in an equation for ‘eval’
  at spec.hs:59:7-15
or from (c10 a0)
  bound by a type expected by the context: (c10 a0) => Bool
  at spec.hs:59:27-43
Relevant bindings include
  x :: a (bound at spec.hs:59:21)
  l :: Pred c3 (bound at spec.hs:59:7)
  eval :: Pred c -> a -> Bool (bound at spec.hs:58:1)
In the first argument of ‘(\\)’, namely ‘eval l x’
In the first argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘(eval l x \\ conjL)’
In the expression: (eval l x \\ conjL) && (eval r x \\ conjR)
```

but also...

```
Could not deduce (c10 a0, c20 a0) arising from a use of ‘\\’
from the context (c a)
  bound by the type signature for
             eval :: (c a) => Pred c -> a -> Bool
  at spec.hs:57:9-34
or from (c ~ (c3 /\ c4))
  bound by a pattern with constructor
             And :: forall (c1 :: * -> Constraint) (c2 :: * -> Constraint).
                    Pred c1 -> Pred c2 -> Pred (c1 /\ c2),
           in an equation for ‘eval’
  at spec.hs:59:7-15
In the first argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘(eval l x \\ conjL)’
In the expression: (eval l x \\ conjL) && (eval r x \\ conjR)
In the expression:
  \ x -> (eval l x \\ conjL) && (eval r x \\ conjR)
```

It's more or less the same story, except now GHC also seems unwilling to unify the variables brought in by the GADT with those required by `conjL`. It looks like *this* time the `/\` in the type of `conjL` *has* been expanded to `(c10 a0, c20 a0)`. (I think this is because `/\` appears fully-applied in `conjL`, not in curried form as it does in `And`.)

Needless to say, it's surprising to me that Scala does this better than Haskell. How can I fiddle with the body of `eval` until it typechecks? Can I cajole GHC into expanding `/\`? Am I going about it the wrong way? Is what I want even possible?

Comment: The data constructor `And :: Pred c1 -> Pred c2 -> Pred (c1 /\ c2)` is not well formed because type families cannot be partially applied. However, ghc earlier than 7.10 will erroneously accept this definition - then give the errors you see when you try to do anything with it. You should use a class instead of a type family; using `class (c1 a, c2 a) => (/\) (c1 :: k -> Constraint) (c2 :: k -> Constraint) (a :: k); instance (c1 a, c2 a) => (c1 /\ c2) a` and the straightforward implementation of `eval` will work.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't realise type families couldn't be partially applied. GHC made me turn on `UndecidableInstances` when I wrote out your suggestion, but it worked fine :) If you want to write that up as a full answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data constructors `And :: Pred c1 -> Pred c2 -> Pred (c1 /\ c2)` and `Or :: ...` are not well formed because type families cannot be partially applied. However, GHC earlier than 7.10 will [erroneously accept this definition](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9433) - then give the errors you see when you try to do anything with it.

You should use a class instead of a type family; for example

```
class (c1 a, c2 a) => (/\) (c1 :: k -> Constraint) (c2 :: k -> Constraint) (a :: k)
instance (c1 a, c2 a) => (c1 /\ c2) a
```

and the straightforward implementation of `eval` will work.